# How to fix Unison error in setting file ownership

Tags: linux, unison

Im trying to sychronize STOR1 and STOR2 on my linux device using unison.
However when I try the following code;

`unison /srv/webdata/html ssh://172.16.3.12//srv/webdata/html -group -batch -silent`

I keep getting the following error;

> Failed [leegBestand]: Error in setting file ownership:
>   Operation not permitted [chown(/srv/webdata/html/.unison.leegBestand.311a006a8ea6cf6f5ed9619764431de8.unison.tmp)]

On my STOR1 *leegBestand* looks like this;

> -rwxrwx--- 1 www-data www-data 0 Mar 26 11:44 leegBestand

And the directory looks like this;

> drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 26 11:44 html

And on my STOR2 the directory looks like this;

> drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 26 11:08 html

Does anyone maybe know how I can fix it in such a way that the file *leegBestand* does get sychronized from STOR1 to STOR2?